# How to access complex array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this to work with:

```
[
  ["app1", {"name"=>"name1", "path"=>"xyz.com/"}],
  ["app2", {"name"=>"name2", "path"=>"xyz.com/"}],
  ["app3", {"name"=>"name3", "path"=>"xyz.com/"}],
  # etc.
]
```

I want to be able to access each name and path so I tried:

```
apps.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |key, value|
    puts value
  end
end
```

but this returns an Enumerator. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Consider creating your own `Class` for that kind of thing - more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apps = [["app1", {"name"=>"name1", "path"=>"https://xyz.com/"}], ["app2", {"name"=>"name2", "path"=>"https:/xyz.com/"}], ["app3", {"name"=>"name3", "path"=>"https://xyz.com/"}]]
apps.flatten.each do |t|
  next unless t.class == Hash
  next unless t.key?("name")
  next unless t.key?("path")
  puts t.inspect # now t is a hash that has both "name" and "path" keys - do what you want
end
```

This will handle even a bit more complex cases when you have different structure for different elements.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing- `apps = apps.flatten
apps = apps.delete_if do |key, value| key.class == String end 
apps.each do |app| puts blah end `

Answer (score 0):

I think your first each loop is only looping over an array, so it would be:

```
apps.each do |app|
  app.each do |key, value|
    puts key   # would be app1 in the first array
    puts value["name"]
    puts value["path"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ar = [
  ["app1", {"name"=>"name1", "path"=>"xyz.com/"}],
  ["app2", {"name"=>"name2", "path"=>"xyz.com/"}],
  ["app3", {"name"=>"name3", "path"=>"xyz.com/"}]

]
#Get a specific app:
p ar.assoc("app2").last["name"]
#Get all names and paths
ar.each{|app|  name, path = app.last["name"], app.last["path"]}
```